# When adding getters, IDEA adds an underscore to variable names

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

In an Angular project, when adding getters, IDEA adds an underscore to variable names.

Is it possible to configure the IDE so that it does the opposite - adds this symbol to getters, but does not change the names of variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDE create names in accordance to JavaScript/TypeScript naming conventions. You can configure it in

- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Code Generation | Naming Conventions | **Field prefix:**
- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Code Generation | Naming Conventions | **Field prefix:**